# PHP/ARRAY/TABLE - My table has too many <tr></tr>

Tags: php, arrays, api

I need a little help, my loops to turn an array into a table works pretty good, except that it adds a ton of extra  to my results.

This is the loop to create a table to display friends from Facebook Graph API.

```
<? 

sort($friends_data['data']);
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach ($friends_data['data'] as $friend)
    {
    $names = substr($friend['name'],0,1);

        if ($names == 'M') {
             echo "<td><ul><a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$friend['id']."' target='_blank'>".$friend['name']."</a></ul></td>"; 
            }

      if (($current_col++)%$cols == 0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
      }
    }
   while (($current_col++)%$cols !=0){
   echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>"; 
?>
```

This is what it spits out (friends removed):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="10" width="100%" ><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: $cols = 5; -- sorry, forgot to include it. its set higher up in the page.

Comment: I don't understand your logic, could you post the output you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't treat any `<td/>` for the case when `($names != 'M')` that it will give you empty `<tr>` without `td`
You just have `<td>` when `($names == 'M')` only

Try this

```
<? 

sort($friends_data['data']);
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach ($friends_data['data'] as $friend)
    {
    $names = substr($friend['name'],0,1);

        if ($names == 'M') {
             echo "<td><ul><a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$friend['id']."' target='_blank'>".$friend['name']."</a></ul></td>"; 
            }
        else
        {
             //this of $name is not 'M'
             //assume empty if $name is not 'M'
             echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
         }

      if (($current_col++)%$cols == 0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
      }
    }
   while (($current_col++)%$cols !=0){
   echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>"; 
?>
```

Or assume if you want to show just `$names == 'M'`

```
<? 

sort($friends_data['data']);
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach ($friends_data['data'] as $friend)
    {
    $names = substr($friend['name'],0,1);

        if ($names == 'M') {
             echo "<td><ul><a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$friend['id']."' target='_blank'>".$friend['name']."</a></ul></td>"; 
            if (($current_col++)%$cols == 0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }              
    }
   while (($current_col++)%$cols !=0){
   echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>"; 
?>
```